# How do I test load balancing in my LAN?

Tags: ubuntu, load-balancing, cluster, pacemaker, corosync

I recently posted a [question regarding the issue of loadbalancing webservers on a budget](https://serverfault.com/questions/243782/load-balancing-apache-on-a-budget). It's finally time to begin the testing so I thought about setting up two or more Ubuntu VM's in my LAN running `pacemaker`+`corosync` in order to learn the basics and try different configs out.

How do I get started after installing both `corosync` + `pacemaker` as I don't have public IP's attached to each VM living in my LAN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use RFC1918 IP addresses to test your configuration.  Depending on the load balancing setup, the use of RFC1918 addresses may continue in some form into production.

Comment: Hi! That's great! Can you please tell me how I would try to access a machine to check whether the load balancing would work or not as the IP of the machine is set by the Router in the LAN and will not follow between the machines on a failure?

Comment: Don't let your "router" set IP addresses of servers.

Comment: Hmm then how should I do it?

Comment: assign a static IP outside of the DHCP range.